# Angular UI-Router not passing params to service call

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-ui-router

First, thanks for your help in advance.  I'm a noob to angular though I did search quite a bit trying to resolve this issue. I'm guessing I missed something obvious.  I'm using ui-router and using the resolve property to call a resource and can't get it for the life of me to pass the params to the web service.

First, my routes and states:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("MyModule",
        ["ui.router",
         "ngResource",
         "common.services"]);
    app.config(["$stateProvider", '$urlRouterProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

            $stateProvider.state("home", {
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: "welcomeView.html"
            })
            $stateProvider.state("vehicleList", {
                url: "/vehicles",
                templateUrl: "App/Vehicles/vehicleListView.html",
                controller: "VehicleListController as vm"
            })
            $stateProvider.state("vehicleEdit", {
                url: "/vehicles/edit/:vin",
                templateUrl: "App/Vehicles/vehicleEditView.html",
                controller: "VehicleEditController as vm",
                resolve: {
                    vehicleResource: "vehicleResource",
                    vehicle: function (vehicleResource, $stateParams) {
                        var vehicleVIN = $stateParams.vin;
                        return vehicleResource.get(
                            { vin: $stateParams.vin }).$promise;

                    }
                }
            })
            $stateProvider.state("vehicleDetails", {
                url: "/vehicles/:vin",
                templateUrl: "App/Vehicles/vehicleDetailsView.html",
                controller: "VehicleDetailsController as vm",
                resolve: {
                    vehicleResource: "vehicleResource",
                    vehicle: function (vehicleResource, $stateParams) {
                        var vehicleVIN = $stateParams.vin;
                        return vehicleResource.get(
                            { vin: 'T123432342' }).$promise;

                    }
                }
            })
        }
    ]);
}());
```

Note that you see a couple of varieties of passing the vin is as I've tried numerous ways with passing in the variable vehicleVIN, a string, etc.  The vehicleVIN variable does assign properly there so injecting $stateParams or passing the vin to it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Here is the resource:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("common.services")
        .factory("vehicleResource",
            ["$resource",
             "appSettings",
            vehicleResource]);

    function vehicleResource($resource, appSettings) {
        return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/Vehicle/:vin", { vin: '@vin' },
            {
                'update': { method: 'PUT' },
                'details': { method: 'GET' },
                'query': { method: 'GET', isArray = true }
            });
    }
}());
```

Here is common.services:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("common.services", ["ngResource"])
        .constant("appSettings",
        {
            serverPath: "http://localhost:8098"
        });
}());
```

And here is the service end of it (Asp.Net WebAPI):

```
// GET api/Vehicle
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All, AllowedOrderByProperties = "Name")]
[ResponseType(typeof(IQueryable<IEnumerable<IVehicle>>))]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return ListOfVehicles...blah..blah
}

// GET api/Vehicle/5
[ResponseType(typeof(IQueryable<IVehicle>))]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string vin)
{
    return SingleVehicle...blah...blah
}
```

Every time I execute it, the breakpoint hits Get (without the vin parameter) and when I run fiddler, it looks like it's sending an empty body.

Any ideas on what is going on?  Much appreciated!

Comment: Does it work when you replace `:vin`with an number?

Comment: No, still doesn't work.  In fact, if you look at the resolve property of the vehicleDetails state, I'm doing just that.

Comment: If I change my Get() controller to return Get(hardcodedVin) it works properly so something is definitely happening with the resolve not passing the param properly or something along those lines.

Comment: Your service doesn't define a function called get(). It only defines update(), details() and query()??? So perhaps return vehicleResource.get({vin...}) needs to be return vehicleResource.details({vin...})  in the resolve  - (just guessing from casting an eye on the code, didn't try running anything...)

Comment: It seems it's defaulting its existence because it is making the call.  Just to be sure, I added get and it didn't change anything.  I don't want to change it to details because that is a different call.  Nevertheless, I tried calling details with the param and that still doesn't pass the parameter along.  I must be missing something very basic here.

Comment: quick check: with an IIFE, the ending order of parens seem slightly off: `}());` ought to be `})();` ?  example: [angular-IIFE](http://toddmotto.com/minimal-angular-module-syntax-approach-using-an-iife/)

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond...I thought I had.  Thanks on the IIFE but that didn't change anything